# Is it possible to tell Sqlite to ignore trailing field separator when using import command?

Tags: import, sqlite, separator, csv

I want to load a table with a text file delimited by pipes

```
Table
--------------------------

Id + Employee + Department

--------------------------
```

File

```
0|Some Name|Some department|
1|Another Name|Another department|
```

I use the .separator command to set the "|" separator
and then execute the .import command.

I receive the following error
Error: EMP.TXT line 1: expected 3 columns of data but found 4.

I want to know if ther is some option in sqlite3 to ignore the trailing pipe.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could import into a temporary table with a dummy column:

```sql
CREATE TEMP TABLE DummyTable(id, emp, dep, nothing);
.import importfile DummyTable
INSERT INTO MyTable SELECT id, emp, dep FROM DummyTable;
DROP TABLE DummyTable;
```

Answer (score 1):

You could remove the superfluous pipe before importing:

```sh
< importfile sed 's/|$//' | sqlite3 my.db ".import /dev/stdin MyTable"
```

Comment: thanks! but I'm using windows and I don't have a robust sustitution tool like sed installed.

Comment: You can use MSYS/MinGW which has `sed` included. I find the Git MinGW environment that comes with [Git for Windows](https://msysgit.github.io/) especially easy to install and use.